# Inherit UINavigationController to reuse menu button in all UIViewControllers

Tags: c#, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller

We want to add a menu button in the top right corner of our Xamarin.iOS app. We know how to do that in each ViewController by setting the NavigationItem object RighBarButtonItem like this:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
   base.ViewDidLoad();
   var menuButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromBundle("ic_menu.png"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, MenuButtonTouchUpInside);


    NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = menuButton;
    searchResultListView.Source = new ObjectFilterTableSource(TableViewData, this);  
}
```

But we don't want to place this button and it's handler in each view controller so we came to the idea of inheriting from UINavigationViewController to place the menu button in the NavigationItem object there, but it seems each view controller gets its own instance of it so no button is shown in our view controllers. Here's our subclassed UINavigationController:

```
public partial class MainNavigationController : UINavigationController
{

    public MainNavigationController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var menuButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Menu", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, MenuButtonTouchUpInside);

        NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(menuButton, false);
    }

    public void MenuButtonTouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("button tapped");
        var viewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MenuViewController") as MenuViewController;
        NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true);
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the menu button is pressed, a new screen with the menu should appear. No fancy side menu bars or something like that. Just a new screen. Simple as it sounds, we couldn't achieve our goal.

We know the code is executed. We know the button is created. Does anybody know what could be the problem here? Is this a valid approach to our main goal, that it is to reuse as maximum code as we can? We don't want the same code repeated in all UIViewControllers classes in our app.

Thanks a lot!